# Multiple Connection Strings in One JSON (App Insights)

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, connection-string, appinsights

I am trying to implement App Insights for my Spring Boot/JAVA application. Is there a way to have multiple connection strings in one JSON. I have multiple JSONs at the moment for each environment (dev/test/prod). But only the connectionString changes, rest of the JSON is the same. So in order to minimize the code, I was wondering if i can have just one JSON with all three connection strings in it.

And the application fetches the right one depending on the environment it is deploying to.

I am new to App Insights, so don't know all the ins and outs. And the documentation is a bit thin. So any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Try defining multiple connection strings in the JSON file like  `{ "ConnectionStrings": {"conn1:"value", "conn2":"value", "conn3":"value"}}`.

Comment: @PravallikaKV Then how does the app know which one to connect to? Can you kindly elaborate.